# How can I enable IIS to run Perl scripts?

Tags: iis, iis-6, perl, http-status-code-404

we're trying to get awstats up and running on our IIS6 server. awstats is running fine and generating output and all that jazz... no problem there.

When trying to change the selected month/year in the output page though, it is trying to run `awstats.pl` through IIS, and coming up with a 404 error. To debug I made a simple `hello.pl` in my root, and tried to run that, also 404s.

I followed the directions on this page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245225 regarding installing ActiveState Perl and then configuring IIS. I added the extension mapping on my directory and registered the web services extension as directed.

The perl scripts all run fine and output if run from the command line, so I know perl is good, but I can't get IIS to find the files.

Here is the configuration on my the home directory tab of my site:
[image: Home Directoy]

Here is the configuration of my web service extension:
[image]

I turned on directory browsing for this site, and when i get the listing of the directory, IIS actually does show the `.pl` files being in the directory. But if I click on one of them, I get the 404 error.

**12/17 15:22 >** Also tried adding .pl as a mime-type on my site's configuration. This did not help.

**12/17 16:57 >** Also tried **Everyone** Read/Execute permissions on both the Perl direcory and the directory housing awstats. This did not help.

Comment: Seems more like a ServerFault question.

Comment: Yah, I couldn't quite decide between the two. I guess I'll cross-post it there.

Comment: @eidylon Don't create a new post on ServerFault. Wait for this topic to be moved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to get this working. Every direction every where that I found talked about pointing the Web Service Extension to `perl.exe`. No matter how I tweaked, I always got 404s.

I finally got it working by instead pointing the web service extension to `perlis.dll`. As soon as I did that - BOOM! It worked! WAHOO!